# $\operatorname{supp}(f_{X,Y})=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2||x|+|y|\leq1\}$ then $X,Y$ are not independent

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, absolute-continuity

Let $Z=(X,Y)$ be a absolutely coninuous random variable such that
$$
\\\operatorname{supp}(f_Z)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2||x|+|y|\leq1\} \
$$
Show that $X,Y$ are not independent.

---

I don't have a good idea how to continue the proof. I need to find $(t,s)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ that setasfies
$$
\\ \int_{-1}^{s}\int_{-1}^{t}f_Z(x,y)dx dy=\int_{-1}^{1}f_Z(t,y)dy\cdot\int_{-1}^{1}f_Z(x,s)dx  \
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Can $X$ and $Y$ simultaneously be close to $1$?  Can you show that each individually has a positive probability of being close to $1$?

---

Hint 2: I mean the following.  Note that since the set $\{x > \frac{1}{2}, y > \frac{1}{2}\}$ intersects the support of $f_Z$ trivially, we must have that $P[X > \frac{1}{2}, Y > \frac{1}{2}] = 0\,.$  To show that they're not independent, you'd just now need to show that $P[X > \frac{1}{2}] > 0$ and $P[Y > \frac{1}{2}] > 0$, since we'd then have $$P\left[X > \frac{1}{2}, Y > \frac{1}{2}\right]  \neq P\left[X > \frac{1}{2}\right] \cdot P\left[Y > \frac{1}{2}\right]\,. $$

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{t\to1}\int_{-1}^{1}f_Z(t,y)dy=\int_{-1}^1f_Z(1,y)dy=\mathbb{P}(-1<Y\leq1)$ and same for $X$? Not sure how it helps me. @Marcuus

Comment: @J.Doe, no that's not what I mean.  I added a second, more involved hint that puts you nearly all the way there.